# Only consume few messages from the Topic or Queue of Tibco EMS

Tags: tibco-ems

My understanding is that consumer by default consumes all the messages from the Topic or Queue. We're using Tibco EMS in our project, what we're looking to always consume 1st message or 1st 10 messages only by giving the certain numbers, so that only those number of messages can be consumed.

How can we do that in Tibco EMS?

Comment: Can you please elaborate when you say 1st message? What type of application which is consuming the messages? Can't it not ignore once it know it has received the message?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use QueueInfo class and check for the pendingmessages or totalmessages before reading the Queue\Topic. Please note that TotalMessageCount statistics should be enabled in EMS and statistics will be reset after the server restart.

```
TibjmsAdmin connection = new TibjmsAdmin(url,username,password);
QueueInfo info = connection.getQueue(queue);
//messages = info.getPendingMessageCount();
messages  = info.getInboundStatistics().getTotalMessages();
connection.close();
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way just to read only one/first message?

Comment: not sure what are you trying to achieve.  You can check for getTotalMessages() == 0 && getPendingMessageCount() > 0 and read only one message.  it will do what you asked.  you also probably can programable reset the queue statistics and remove all the pending messages if needed.